# Cakephp routing to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, cakephp-2.0

Is it possible to route from cakephp 2.5 to Laravel 5.1?

Both apps are in the same host and both apps share the same database.
In Laravel I have a trait that checks if there is a logged in session.

Can I pass a url to a cakephp route?

Comment: Well sure. Overall it's just a URL. As long as there are no route collisions between cake and laravel you should be fine.

Comment: Even if there's a URL collision only the mother Framework(which holds another framework) will work.

Comment: may i redirect passing the url into a single header php function inside the controller ?